# DELETE statement php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I need some help with my code, When I click the submit code it always says "User successfully kicked". However, the query is not executed successfully, the user is still in the database.

edit: Fixed mysql/msqli problem. Query now answers "Something went wrong" in stead of "User successfully kicked". But I wont get any errors from the mysql_error report. What could I do?

```
include 'connect.php';

if(empty($_POST['user_id'])) 
    {
            echo '<form method="post" action="">
                  User_id: <input type="text" name="user_id" />
                 <input type="submit" value="Kick user" />
                 </form>';

    }
    else 
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM users
                WHERE 
                user_id = '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']) . "'
                ";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if($result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo 'Something went wrong!.';
            echo mysqli_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'User successfully kicked!';
        }
    }
```

My connect.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","dps");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "failed to connect mysql: ". mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: Your SQL string is made in the wrong block of the `if ... else ...` statement.

Comment: You are mixing APIs.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and do some error checking on your database items.

Comment: Your conditional statement if/else is wrong.

Comment: When adding error reports at the top i won't get errors. Also my database seems to work propper on other pages i made. Thanks for helping so far!

Comment: `mysql_` + `mysqli_` = NO LOVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your `$sql` var in the `if` part and try to access it in the `else` part. This does not work.
Also you are mixing libraries which is bad (mysql is not the same as mysqli, use mysqli because **mysql is deprecated and will be removed from php**)

```
include 'connect.php';

if(empty($_POST['user_id'])) 
{
        echo '<form method="post" action="">
              User_id: <input type="text" name="user_id" />
             <input type="submit" value="Kick user" />
             </form>';

}
else 
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users
            WHERE 
            user_id = '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_id']) . "'
            ";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(!$result)
    {
        //something went wrong, display the error
        echo 'Something went wrong!: ';
        echo mysqli_error($con) //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'User succesfully kicked!';
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
}
```

You may need to alter connect.php to use mysqli

Edit: There where some errors they should be fixed now

Comment: Read up on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php then modify your answer accordinly ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Add :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

After :

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM 
                    users
                WHERE 
                    user_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']) . "'
                ";
```

Comment: Not your DV, but if mysqli is in use, parameter binding would probably be better. Your escaping function is incorrect, too - don't mix `mysql` with `mysqli` functions.

Comment: @halfer actually, adding an `i` and passing DB connection needs to be done. But parametrized is better.

Comment: Another tip @Maikel: remember that the phrase "it doesn't work" on its own doesn't give people anything new to respond to. Try to be more detailed about the problem instead.